# Getting specific values by regex in from a list transformed into str

Tags: python, string

I've took values from a Json file which containes values as :

```
{"goodies" : ['banana : yellow', 'kiwi : green']}
```

there's a lot more than that but, so I get the values from that dictionnary to a list with :

```
mylist = [*goodies.values()]
```

So I wanted with str(mylist) get the values of each item splitting with the ':' , I have tried to put

```
for veggies in mylist:
  fruit, color= str(veggies).split(':')
  print(fruit, color)
```

but then it has too many values to unpacked, so how can I do ? Because that's not a dictionnary and when splitting there are still the [' that I don't want, if someone know please I am not able to find out ?

Comment: Have you tried `print(veggies)` to figure out what exactly you are trying to split?

Comment: yes I’ve tried and I got : ['banana : yellow', 'kiwi : green'] the list as itself

Comment: So maybe `[*goodies.values()]` isn't doing what you think it's doing

Comment: ohh yeah I was thinking also it puts it into a list but with keys and values I am not able to get banana and ginger since it’s not : “banana“ : "ginger" , and file modifying is complicating with regex for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you might have multiple lists of values in your `dict` which is why you would be taking this approach.  As pointed out, since the values are a list, the `.values()` method is returning a list of lists, which is fine but you need to handle that.

You can either use a nested loop, or use some other method to join the lists together.  Here are both examples using a dict with two keys.

```
goodies = {"goodies" : ['banana : yellow', 'kiwi : green'],
          "goodies2": ['apple : red','orange : orange']}
# Each list of values
for l in goodies.values():
    # Each value in list
    for veggies in l:
        fruit, color= str(veggies).split(':')
        print(fruit, color)
```

Another great choice

```
from itertools import chain
# Chain all of the lists of values together
for veggies in chain.from_iterable(goodies.values()):
    fruit, color= str(veggies).split(':')
    print(fruit, color)
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot I used itertools which I didn't knew the existence of! So I am really grateful for your help! I've exactly got what I was looking for since many hours! thanks again haha

Comment: @Jay Itertools has a TON of awesome stuff you should spend some time looking at the documentation

Comment: yeeees! already started it looks awesome as a first impression!! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The line `mylist = [*goodies.values()]` results in a double list: `[['banana : yellow', 'kiwi : green']]`, which is why it is saying there are too many values to unpack.

Try this instead:

```
dict_ = {"goodies" : ['banana : yellow', 'kiwi : green']}
for goodie in dict_["goodies"]:
    fruit, color = goodie.split(' : ')
    print(fruit, color)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is;

```
mylist = [*goodies.values()]
```

creates a nested list as;

```
[['banana : yellow', 'kiwi : green']]
```

To avoid that you can simply do;

```
mylist = list(*goodies.values()) # ['banana : yellow', 'kiwi : green']


goodies = {"goodies" : ['banana : yellow', 'kiwi : green']}
mylist = list(*goodies.values())
for veggies in mylist:
  fruit, color= str(veggies).split(':')
  print(f'{fruit} - {color}')
```

which gives

```
banana  -  yellow
kiwi  -  green
```